# How can I communicate between two computers with different network ? Server(192.168.1.2) and client side (10.0.0.30)

Tags: networking

I have an internal communication system between the server and the client, whereas the server side is configured with 19.168.1.2 and I have client-side with the same range of IP and I could able to make a ping via a normal router and now I would like to add a new wireless modem with IP 10.0.0.30 and 10.0.0.10 as its default gateway. I could not able to communicate with the server-side (192.168.1.2) or could not able to make a ping in the network.

Comment: You need to ensure each IP network's router knows how to route packets for certain networks. That is, the router for `192.168.1.0/24` network needs to know that packets destined to `10.0.0.0/24` network need to be sent to router for that network. Study how IP forwarding works and you'll see how to do it.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a simple diagram.  It's not clear from your description how things are connected.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/q/1032893/590406

Comment: In the above link I have added the image and it will be easy to identify. Thank you sir